Setting a cursor for a QT application in linux
I am using qt5ct to set the theme for my QT applications... A few days ago I changed my cursor theme in Cinnamon (Debian 12 Stable) to MacOS like cursor. But inside QT applications (VLC, VirtualBox, and some other day-to-day softwares) the cursor is different. The comparison is given


How do I set the cursor on the left (default cursor) as the default in qt apps as well?? I've searched over internet and I can't find anything except the QCursor class of Qt applications (I don't know what that does or what it means) but I know that it is for developers developing applications in qt.

To set the cursor theme:
add these lines with YOUR CURSOR THEME NAME:
[Icon Theme]
Inherits=YOUR-CURSOR-THEME-NAME
Name=YOUR-CURSOR-THEME-NAME

to your ~/.icons/default/index.theme file
To set the cursor size:
add a line with desired size:
export XCURSOR_SIZE=48

to your ~/.profile file,
or to /etc/profile.d/qt_mouse_pointer_size.sh file for system wide,
and relog.
